# Logical Effort in complex circuit - Output capacitance

Tags: digital-logic, vlsi, alu

As part of a VLSI course I was asked to estimate the delay of an ALU, similar to the one described in the picture, using Logical Effort method.

I calculated the delay of the critical path through the ADD/SUB block, but I am not sure how the output capacitance of the multiplexer is calculated. Do I need to take into account all the blocks that enter the multiplexer in order to get the output capacitance needed to calculate the delay through ADD/SUB block only? Or can I just ignore the inactive blocks when calculating the delay of an active block?

[image: ALU]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The logical effort of the entire gate is the ratio of its output logical effort to the sum of its input logical efforts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_effort). The answer depends on a schematics of your mux. It may happen that you need to consider all the signal paths within multiplexer.